# How can I respond to a deleted answer wisely?

Tags: support

One of my answers regarding 'Time' was deleted a few days ago. I don't know the reason. I am not allowed to give a reply to a doubt I was asked (in comments). Since almost all my answers are very brief it is not good to me to keep mum without giving my explanation. Since they are brief, most often my answers seem as something written by a person who follows some orthodox beliefs. So I must give an explanation. How can I convey him my answer indirectly? (i.e., by Stack Exchange only). As I was busy it took me a few days' time to make a draft regarding his question.

Since it is an explanation, **I think my answer regarding Time,** **would be useful to many brilliant users. I am sure.**

The question was: **"Is time a physical factor or just a concept?"** (in Philosophy section).

Though this question seems normal, when one goes deep, it transcends all the levels.  Actually one can already derive the answer from those famous verses I gave.

Partial 'death' will happen to the 'person' (or *birth* of the *person* will happen) when 'trying' to find **the answer** to certain questions.  A mere-Materialist can't do anything with his educational qualifications in such cases. All the experiments using equipments fail here. That Gordian knot regarding 'Time' also is one such type.  That is why many uneducated persons can still transcend Time. If you wish to look into its depths, try to verify this statement: **"Even Educational Qualification is a product of Time"**.  **If so, when standing on it and evaluating, what kind of an answer would it be? What would be its level?** (FYI, This is a very very rare case.)

The first part of the reply I wished to give in the comment is [this](http://pix.toile-libre.org/?img=1425720610.png). I am allowed to give only two links here. So I am unable to give all the four screen shots.

Presentation of one of those great works of that great *Guru* will be given by a *Sanyasi* at the 2015 Parliament of the World's Religions.

Comment: If it was your answer, you can always edit it whether it's deleted or not. That reply would not fit into a comment.

Comment: Thanks. But that answer is seen nowhere now.

Comment: You can find it at the bottom of your list of answers - see 'recent deleted answers'

Comment: Somehow I could edit it. I don't know whether it is visible to all users. Thanks.

Comment: Right now you can add in all the links you need -- there's a restriction on users with less than 10 reputation points.

Comment: Deleted posts are visible to mods, staff, and users with 10K+ reputation.

Comment: If you want a user to see a response to a comment on a post they didn't write, you need to "ping" them, by adding the`@` symbol before their username. I'm not sure if @Woodface saw your response to their comment.

Comment: Thanks for these continuous effort for me.Kindly close this question.

Answer (score 3):

You could create a new chat room, type your response to that user, and invite him to the room. That way, there is no limit on how much content you want to send.

Comment: Good. I was trying to answer that question in Philosophy without changing the main answer and using two great works of a great man. The answer was in them.  But it was mistaken. Since it is beyond all sciences very few people only will be able to understand it. You may verify all these 4 screenshots. 1. http://pix.toile-libre.org/?img=1443182382.png  2. http://pix.toile-libre.org/?img=1443182540.png  3. http://pix.toile-libre.org/?img=1443182624.png  4. http://pix.toile-libre.org/?img=1443182713.png

Comment: Though my answer is still invisible there, the main problem mentioned here was solved already in March. Now I have quit this question completely. You may decide whether these are suitable for chatting.Thank you for the risk you took to answer an abandoned question. Good bye.

Comment: @Madhusoodanan Risk? I'm not sure I follow you.

Comment: See: http://pix.toile-libre.org/?img=1443889030.png